# How to view contents of infinispan cache?

Tags: infinispan

I am using the infinispan cache in a grails project.

Is there any way I can hit a JMX port or anything to see the contents of the cache?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here are [docs for JMX operations](http://docs.jboss.org/infinispan/6.0/apidocs/jmxComponents.html). And no, there is no JMX operation that would show all entries.

In local/replicated mode, you can call values() on the cache to get all values, but this is not a recommended operation for production (it does not scale very well). Instead, look on Distributed Executors or Map/Reduce API.

Comment: The only operations exposed for the Cache MBean are start() and stop()

Comment: Yes, I've written that there is no JMX operation that would show all entries. Simply said, listing all entries is not a think you should do. If you want to do something with all entries, parallel approach with Map/Reduce API is the way to go.